# positioning a javascript image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I got 2 tilesheet image and ive completely done the rendering but i cant figure out how to put the character in front of the map.

[image]

I place those image in 2 different js file.

This is the character js file:
'

```js
function drawFrame(frameX, frameY, canvasX, canvasY) {
  ctx.drawImage(img,
  frameX * WIDTH, frameY * HEIGHT, WIDTH, HEIGHT,
  canvasX, canvasY, SCALED_WIDTH, SCALED_HEIGHT);
}

loadImage();
```

`
This is the map js file:

```js
function drawMap() {
   for (var r = 0; r < rowTileCount; r++) {
      for (var c = 0; c < colTileCount; c++) {
         var tile = ground[ r ][ c ];
         var tileRow = (tile / imageNumTiles) | 0;
         var tileCol = (tile % imageNumTiles) | 0;
         ctx.drawImage(tilesetImage, (tileCol * tileSize), (tileRow * tileSize), tileSize, tileSize, (c * tileSize), (r * tileSize), tileSize, tileSize);
      }
   }window.requestAnimationFrame(drawMap);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` is continuing to call `drawMap()` again and again after every time the function is called. That means if the first image has been drawn once, then the map will be drawn over it on this second animation frame (and every frame after that).

To simplify your process, create one function that calls all your draw methods, so that you can control the order in which the items are drawn. Then use `requestAnimationFrame` in this function instead of your current `drawFrame` function, so that every item is redrawn on each frame, in the order you want.

```js
function drawEverything() {

    drawMap();
    drawFrame();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawEverything);
}
```

Now call `drawEverything()` when you are ready to start the animation.

One more thing: if items will be moving anywhere in your canvas animation, you should clear the canvas on each new draw. Otherwise, the canvas will become a mess of colors very quickly.

```js
function drawEverything() {

    // Erase the current frame
    // (Note: replace 400 here with your canvas width, and 300 with its height)
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 300);

    drawMap();
    drawFrame();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(drawEverything);
}
```

Comment: Hey it works!!! Thank you very much @tlong314!! I really appreciate it.